# Unconnected lookup sql override issue

Tags: etl, lookup, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have unconnected lookup lkp_tst with the below ports - `x,y,z` - all these 3 fields are strings.
This unconnected lookup port has x as the return port
Also added i/p port (ipp) - to define the lookup cond

```
Cond: x=ipp
```

Written SQL override query in lookup transf. as

```
select x+''+y+''+z as x from test
```

the test table is created in SQL server DB

From the `expr. transf.` - am calling the unconnected lkp

```
:lkp.lkp_tst('abc')
```

Now when I try to try to debug it - it always returns

But however when I don't override the query in lkp transformation - I see the x  been returned.

> My objective is to return the concatenated value from the unconnected
> lookup. Please advise.

Comment: Version used to create this unconnected lookup was on  : Informatica Powercenter Designer Version - 10.2.0

Comment: Since you have three ports you should have three columns in the override query. `select x+''+y+''+z as x from test` this query will have only one column

Comment: Initially i added all 3 columns in the override query, it didnt work ....when debugged it didnt return anything (<No data available>) ......read somewhere that we need to include only the field that is used in the return port, so i tried with that, but it is still the same.

Comment: No you have to include all three columns and provide proper alias. And the sequence of the port and the sequence of the columns in the query should be same